# Ruby - How to isolate the first digit of every element in an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, compare, element, digits

i have an array with numbers like this:

list1 = [50, 2, 99, 1, 958, 9, 6, 80]

and i need to compare all elements: digit by digit.
for exemple, it will be important to compare "9", "99" and "958", because i'll need to put "99" at the end like this:

list1 = [1, 2, 50, 6, 80, 9, 958, 99]

Does Ruby has a function for this?
thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Can you provide some more context on your sorting rules? You can use `list1.map(&:to_s).sort` to convert to strings and that sorts it like what I _think_ you're asking, but your 2nd example doesn't have the first half of your list sorted (e.g. why does 50 sort before 2?)

Comment: Hey! i have to write the biggest number with all the elements of the array. for example : [50, 2, 1, 9] should output the number "95021". that's why i have to compare the elements digits by digits. (and sorry for my 2nd example, i didn't check the beginning of the array ;) )

Comment: "Sorry for my 2nd example"? Are you referring to the example in your question? If so, why haven't you edited the question to fix it? I see you are new to SO, but isn't it common sense that you should correct errors in your question? Also, if you want to construct a string (e.g, "95021"), why don't you say that in your question?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
list1.sort_by(&:to_s)
```

So, this will lead to:

```
[50, 2, 99, 1, 958, 9, 6, 80].sort_by(&:to_s)
#=> [1, 2, 50, 6, 80, 9, 958, 99]

[50, 2, 1, 9].sort_by(&:to_s)
#=> [1, 2, 50, 9]
```

If you want reverse order, you can do:

```
[50, 2, 99, 1, 958, 9, 6, 80].sort_by(&:to_s).reverse
#=> [99, 958, 9, 80, 6, 50, 2, 1] 

[50, 2, 1, 9].sort_by(&:to_s).reverse
#=> [9, 50, 2, 1]
```

And you can do .`join` to get the joined string:

```
[50, 2, 1, 9].sort_by(&:to_s).reverse.join
#=> "95021"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: compare values converted to string, using [String#<=>](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) with [Array#sort](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html#method-i-sort):

```
list1.sort { |a, b| a.to_s <=> b.to_s }
#=> [1, 2, 50, 6, 80, 9, 958, 99]
```

If I understand the question, even if the first three element of your output are confusing me about the logic.

Comment: While this seemed correct, and elegant at first glance, this doesn't actually work. The `<=>` comparator assumes that the longer string is greater than the shorter string (when leading characters are the same). However, in this case, the shorter string should be considered greater. `[10, 9, 95]` is already sorted as per this logic, but `95910` is less than `99510`.

Answer (score -1):

To extract just the first digit, you just need to map twice:

```rb
list = [50, 2, 99, 1, 958, 9, 6, 80]

p list.map(&:to_s).map { |n| n[0] }
# => ["5", "2", "9", "1", "9", "9", "6", "8"]
```

**Update:** The solution I've linked below is **incorrect**. The problem isn't as simple as it seemed.

Old answer follows:

> However, the problem itself looked interesting, so I gave it a shot - i.e, to form the largest possible number from a list of numbers.
>  
>  However, I don't want to spoil the fun for you, so here's a [link to a gist that solves the problem through normalization](https://gist.github.com/harigopal/80cd21c7ac7e0a349746a2e0abc63b7e), in case you're interested.

Comment: many thanks for your help Jay Dorsey & Hari Gopal! i will try the "double mapping" tomorrow and of course i'll check your solution, it's always interesting to read others methods ;)

Comment: i tried it and this is perfect!!!! i was thinking about converting it to string but i wasn't sure about how to proceed after that! thank you everyone for your help :)